# Event not running properly

Tags: mysql, events

I need to create an automated event in `MYSQL` to update the status of orders to "Fulfilled" if current date is 2 days more than order date. My event needs to run once everyday.

Here is what I have created :

```
CREATE EVENT updorder
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
        DO
        update orders 
        set order_status = "Fulfilled"
        where order_dt + INTERVAL 2 DAY < DATETIME
```

I also did this :

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

SHOW PROCESSLIST 
309 event_scheduler localhost   NULL    Daemon  125 Waiting for next activation NULL
```

What should I do to get this event to activate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event is probably firing but not doing the intended `UPDATE` cause the below `WHERE` condition don't makes sense (`DATETIME` is a datatype)

```
where order_dt + INTERVAL 2 DAY < DATETIME
```

I think you meant to check `less than current date time`

```
where order_dt + INTERVAL 2 DAY < NOW()
```

(OR)

```
WHERE DATE_ADD(order_dt, INTERVAL 2 DAY) < NOW()
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. It works now. I tested it by changing the event to :CREATE EVENT updorder
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        DO
        update orders 
        set order_status = "Fulfilled"
        where order_dt + INTERVAL 2 DAY < DATETIME